# Conditional Formatting to cells that contain certain formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, match, array-formulas, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight with conditional formatting the cells that contain **ARRAYFORMULA** (just the formula cell, not the whole array). How could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to highlight formula you can use

```
=ISFORMULA(A1)
```

to highlight only arrayformula formulas you can do:

```
=REGEXMATCH(FORMULATEXT(A1); "(?i)arrayformula")
```